# Moving an image with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I am attempting a tug of war game using Node.js and Socket.io and I am confused about how I should proceed. My idea is to move an image left if left button is clicked, and right if right button is clicked. To actually get the image to move, I assume I need a function in `app.js`. How should I go about implementing that?  I have my `server.js` file set up like this:

```
socket.on('tug', function (side) {
    if(side == "left"){
        console.log("left button clicked");
        leftPos++;
        rightPos--;
        pos[0] = leftPos;
        pos[1] = rightPos;
        console.log(pos);
    }
    else if (side == "right"){
        console.log("right button clicked");
        leftPos--;
        rightPos++; 
        pos[0] = leftPos;
        pos[1] = rightPos;
        console.log(pos);
    }
});
```

Then in my app.js I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#left").on('click', function(){
        socket.emit('tug', 'left');
    });
    $("#right").on('click', function(){
        socket.emit('tug', 'right');
    });
});
```

Comment: Need to ask this, are you playing tug of war with yourself?

Comment: For right now, yes. But I will add the feature later on to make it multiplayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the clients, you should add two more socket listeners,

1) One to assign player to one side

2) To listen to moves made

something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    socket.emit('ready');
});

socket.on('assign', function(side){
    if(side==='left') {
        $("#left").on('click', function(){
            socket.emit('tug', 'left');
        });
    } else {
        $("#right").on('click', function(){
            socket.emit('tug', 'right');
        });
    }
});
socket.on('move', function(newPos){
    $("#rope").css({left: newPos});
});
```

where, `#rope` is your rope, maybe with `position:absolute` set

And just to simplify things on the server you could use just the center and move it around, and define the limits at the end, to decide the winner

```
ropeCenter = 300;
socket.on('tug', function (side) {
    if(side == "left"){
        console.log("left button clicked");
        ropeCenter--;
    }
    else if (side == "right"){
        console.log("right button clicked");
        ropeCenter ++; 
    }

    //If you're planning to maintain rooms use io.sockets.in('room').emit below

    if(rope > 100 && ropeCenter<500 )     //Someone must have toppled by now, right?
        io.sockets.emit('move',ropeCenter);     
    else {
        console.log('We have a winner');
        io.sockets.emit('end');
    }
});

assignFirst = true;
socket.on('ready', function(){
   if(assignFirst){
       socket.emit('left');
       assignFirst = false;
   } else {
       socket.emit('right');
   }
});
```

Comment: One follow up question. When I first click the button, the image jumps to the far right. After that, the image does move left to right as expected. Do you know what could be causing the image to jump over in such manner?

Comment: You should keep only one of the listeners on for each player.

Comment: Updated answer. Sorry, if I took away all the fun of implementing this :)

Comment: Didn't take the fun out. I appreciate the input

Comment: What is the role of assignFirst and socket.on('assign',...)?

Comment: Its a crude switch. One of the players will emit `ready` first, server will respond to that socket with `left` and turn off the flag, so the second player's socket will get the `right` from the second block

Comment: Have update with minor changes to the socket broadcasts for 'move' and 'end'. These should be emitted to both players simultaneously. Previously, we were just sending it to only that socket that made the move